# Updatable VIEW doesn't work with ON CONFLICT in Postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.5

PostgreSQL version: `9.5.4`

I have a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_1 (
ID       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
C1       BYTEA,
C2       TEXT NOT NULL,
C3       BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
CONSTRAINT TEST_1_unique_idx UNIQUE(C1, C2)
);
```

I have a view defined as:

```
create or replace view test as select * from test_1 with cascaded check
option;
```

This is necessary to abstract from table name while application code is
working via view name (to implement a kind of simple partitioning with replacing tables when needed)

When I run the following query on **view**:

```
insert into test (c1, c2, c3) values (decode('MTIzAAE=', 'base64'), 'text', true) on conflict (c1, c2) do update set c3=excluded.c3
```

I get the following error:

```
[0A000] ERROR: ON CONFLICT is not supported on table "test" used as a catalog table
  Position: 83
```

But the same query on **table** works as expected. According to Postgres documentation this should work with view as well since ON CONFLICT is fully supported with updatable views https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createview.html

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Please show us the definition of the table `test_1` and the actual Java code that runs your statement (with and without the PreparedStatement)

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for prompt reply! While I was preparing a test code for you I've managed to reproduce the issue without PgPreparedStatement. I've update description, you can find all the details needed to reproduce

Comment: The problem is the `with check option`. If you remove that it works. As you don't restrict the rows in the view, why are you using `with check option` anyway?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Initially the view was more tricky and `with check option` was required. The logic changed but `with check option` remained. Thanks for pointing that out. You are right, it's not needed any more. Without `with check option` it works fine. Thanks a lot! Any ideas why this is happening `with check option`? According to documentation there are no such limitations, should I report this as a bug to Postgres community?

Comment: Seeing the error message, I would guess that's more a documentation bug (oversight) then a bug in the implementation. The `ON CONFLICT` can't properly work if you restrict the rows returned by the view.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : please promote/convert your comment to an answer. IMHO this might be useful for future readers, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is not supported for views that use `with check option`

If you remove `with cascaded check option` this works.

This is not explicitly mentioned in the manual, so this might be a documentation oversight.