# PostgreSQL - ON CONFLICT UPDATE with view with subset of columns

Tags: postgresql

Currently running version 9.5.3.  Update planned, of course.

I have a PostgreSQL database whose schema pre-dates table row-level security (i.e. `CREATE POLICY ...`). Row-level security was implemented using views. The security is done in the view by selecting only rows that have the ownername matching `CURRENT_USER`.

I'm trying to build an upsert query using such a view. The problem comes when I try to name the `conflict_target`.

The problem with using `ON CONFLICT UPDATE ...` comes from naming what constraint has been violated.

## Toy Example

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id serial, num int, word text, data text, ownername varchar(64));
```

For each user, the combinations of `word` and `num` must be unique.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_num_word_owner_idx ON foo (num, word, ownername);
```

The row-level security is implemented using a view based on the current user name. Permission is granted for the view, and removed for the underlying table for ordinary user. `security_barrier` was added after v 9.5. Note that users don't see `ownername`.

```
CREATE VIEW foo_user WITH (security_barrier = True) AS
    SELECT id, num, word, data FROM foo 
    WHERE foo.ownername = CURRENT_USER;
```

Now auto-set ownername:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trf_set_owner() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    NEW.ownername = CURRENT_USER::varchar(64);   
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        NEW.ownername = CURRENT_USER::varchar(64);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER foo_row_owner
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON foo FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_set_owner();
```

Note that the `ownername` column is not displayed in the view; the row security is invisible to the user.

Now add some data:

```
INSERT INTO foo_user (num, word, data) VALUES (1, 'asdf', 'cat'), (2, 'qwer', 'dog');


SELECT * FROM foo;
-- normally, this would give an error related to privileges,
-- because we don't allow users to query the underlying table.
-- bypassed here for demo purposes.

 id | num | word | data | ownername
----+-----+------+------+-----------
  1 |   1 | asdf | cat  | admin
  2 |   2 | qwer | dog  | admin
(2 rows)


SELECT * FROM foo_user;

 id | num | word | data
----+-----+------+------
  1 |   1 | asdf | cat
  2 |   2 | qwer | dog
(2 rows)
```

So far, so good.

## What I've Tried

As stated above, for each user, `num` and `word` must be unique. There is no problem with different owners having the same `num` and `word` (in fact, we expect it).

I'm  trying to take advantage of the `ON CONFLICT` clause in `INSERT` to create some back-end UPSERT-ish functionality. And it's falling down.

### Simple example of error

First, a simple failed insert:

```
INSERT INTO foo_user (num, word, data) VALUES (2, 'qwer', 'frog');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_num_word_owner_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (num, word, ownername)=(2, qwer, admin) already exists.
```

Entirely expected. Nothing wrong with that.

### ON CONFLICT, first attempt

Now we try to make the client experience a bit smoother:

```
INSERT INTO foo_user (num, word, data) VALUES (2, 'qwer', 'frog')
    ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE 
    SET data = 'frog'
    WHERE num = 2 AND word = 'qwer';

ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name
LINE 2:     ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
            ^
HINT:  For example, ON CONFLICT (column_name).
```

Yep, just like the documentation says. It needs to know what rule it broke. No problem:

### ON CONFLICT, second attempt

```
INSERT INTO foo_user (num, word, data) VALUES (2, 'qwer', 'frog')
    ON CONFLICT (num, word, ownername) DO UPDATE 
    SET data = 'frog'
    WHERE num = 2 AND word = 'qwer';

ERROR:  column "ownername" does not exist
LINE 2:     ON CONFLICT (num, word, ownername) DO UPDATE
```

True. Ownername does not exist in the view. We can't drop `ownername` from the unique index, because we fully expect different owners to have identical `num` and `word` values.

### ON CONFLICT, third attempt

So I tried converting the index to a constraint, and naming the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE foo 
    ADD CONSTRAINT foo_num_word_owner_crt UNIQUE 
    USING INDEX foo_num_word_owner_idx;

NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD CONSTRAINT USING INDEX will rename index 
"foo_num_word_owner_idx" to "foo_num_word_owner_crt"
```

Ok, now to test:

```
INSERT INTO foo_user (num, word, data) VALUES (2, 'qwer', 'frog')
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT foo_num_word_owner_crt DO UPDATE 
    SET data = 'frog'
    WHERE num = 2 AND word = 'qwer';

ERROR:  constraint "foo_num_word_owner_crt" for table "foo_user" does not exist
```

Well that makes sense: we're querying on the view but specifying a table constraint.

## Conclusion

Now I'm out of ideas. How do we get `ON CONFLICT` to play nice with views like this? Or is it not possible?

I'm *this close* (holds up thumb and forefinger) to proposing we switch from views to tables with row-level security, but that's rather a lot of work (not necessarily an API-breaker, but still).

Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: At this point, your approach will never work. With `security_barrier`, the view is considered a catalog table (just like with [`CHECK OPTION`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260920/updatable-view-doesnt-work-with-on-conflict-in-postgres-9-5)) and `ON CONFLICT` never works on those relations (as of now). If you remove `security_barrier`, you'll get to the problem, where the constraint is neither on the view, [nor could be inferred](http://rextester.com/BZHQ75314) -- which was your conclusion too.

Comment: But, maybe there is a solution, still: the views in postgresql uses the [rule system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules.html). Technically it is possible to rewrite plain `INSERT` queries on the view to execute `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...` queries on the table. Or you could write [`INSTEAD OF` triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) too. I must admit, they provide a way more specific solution: you can only write your [*conflict_action*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) once.

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent the issue by removing the `ON CONFLICT` clause and using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that manually tests for any index conflict:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trf_set_num_word() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Check if (num, word, ownername) exists by trying an UPDATE
    UPDATE foo SET data = 'frog'
    WHERE num = NEW.num AND word = NEW.word AND ownername = CURRENT_USER::varchar(64);   
    IF FOUND THEN
        RETURN NULL; -- If so, don't INSERT/UPDATE
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW; -- If not, do the INSERT
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER foo_user_num_word
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON foo_user FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_set_num_word();
```

Comment: Nah, `security_barrier` is one of the problems. [With it, the view is considered as a catalog table](http://rextester.com/YNUH82567), & PostgreSQL will not even try to infer the constraint (vs. [without `security_barrier`](http://rextester.com/BZHQ75314)) -- This seems to be the [same oversight in the documentation as `WITH CHECK OPTION`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260920/updatable-view-doesnt-work-with-on-conflict-in-postgres-9-5)